# Have Angular 2 resolve base path from root instead of current path when using templateUrl

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app and I'm using the old `templateUrl` to load the HTML template from a URL on the same same server.

```
templateUrl: '/components/directive/directive.html'
```

I'm on a path `/loaded/path/` which is where my directive loads on.

It used to work fine in Angular 1, but in Angular 2 it throws this error

```
Could not resolve the url /components/directive/directive.html from http://example.com/loaded/path/
Error
    at new BaseException (http://example.com/angular2.sfx.dev.js:10986:25)
    at UrlResolver.System.register.execute.UrlResolver.resolve
```

I guess one solution is to add `../../`

```
templateUrl: '../../components/directive/directive.html'
```

but what if I'm on `/some/other/loaded/path` where I use my directive

Is there a way to tell Angular 2 to resolve the path from the root rather than current path?

Comment: I realize this post is very very late, but I use Webpack to provide root for imports.

Comment: Is this still a problem? In Angular 2 final, I've never seen this behaviour and paths are always relative to the `<base href>` tag.

Comment: There is no way to do this unless you use Webpack and require the template so that it'll be turned into JavaScript. If you have a directive which should be used in more than one module, you should make a shared module, declare and export it there and import the shared module in the ones using the directive.